Why does command substitution change the behaviour of a name referenced parameter of a function?
Background
I want to output a string while updating a variable using a name reference. I came up with something like this:
#!/bin/bash

function update_name_ref_and_echo () {
    local -n name_ref=$1
    name_ref="new value"
    echo "bar"
}

foo="old value"
echo "foo before: $foo"

update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo'
echo "foo after: $foo"

It works perfectly as expected:
foo before: old value
bar
foo after: new value

The problem
However, when I try to capture the string echoed from the function using command substitution, the name reference no longer works.
#!/bin/bash

function update_name_ref_and_echo () {
    local -n name_ref=$1
    name_ref="new value"
    echo "bar"
}

foo="old value"
echo "foo before: $foo"

capture=$(update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo')
echo "capture: $capture"
echo "foo after: $foo"

generates:
foo before: old value
capture: bar
foo after: old value

The question

Why does command substitution change the behaviour of a name referenced parameter of a function?
Is there any way to capture the output of echo while allow a name referenced parameter to be modified at the same time?

Further information
My bash version seems to be relative recent.
❯ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Update
The behaviour of directly modifying global variable also changed by command substitution.
#!/bin/bash

GLOBAL_FOO="old value"
echo "GLOBAL_FOO before: $GLOBAL_FOO"

function update_global_and_echo () {
    GLOBAL_FOO="new value"
    echo "bar"
}

update_global_and_echo
echo "GLOBAL_FOO after: $GLOBAL_FOO"

generates:
GLOBAL_FOO before: old value
bar
GLOBAL_FOO after: new value

While
#!/bin/bash

GLOBAL_FOO="old value"
echo "GLOBAL_FOO before: $GLOBAL_FOO"

function update_global_and_echo () {
    GLOBAL_FOO="new value"
    echo "bar"
}

capture=$(update_global_and_echo 'foo')
echo "capture: $capture"
echo "GLOBAL_FOO after: $GLOBAL_FOO"

generates:
GLOBAL_FOO before: old value
capture: bar
GLOBAL_FOO after: old value


See Access variables set inside command substitutions.

Also see BashFAQ/084 (How do I return a string (or large number, or negative number) from a function? "return" only lets me give a number from 0 to 255.).  There's no good way to return values other than small non-negative integers from Bash functions.  Using a global variable is often the least bad way, and sometimes the only practical way.

capture=$(update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo') executes update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo' in a subshell and so foo only has the new value within that subshell, not after the subshell dies.
Assuming you don't want to (or can't) change the definition of update_name_ref_and_echo, you can avoid executing it in a subshell using either of these approaches:

With a coprocess:
coproc CAT { cat; } || exit 1
trap 'kill -9 "$CAT_PID"; exit' EXIT

update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo' >&"${CAT[1]}" &&
IFS= read -r capture <&"${CAT[0]}"


With a temp file:
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo' >"$tmp" &&
IFS= read -r capture <"$tmp"



or you can call update_name_ref_and_echo in a subshell but print the resultant value of foo from within the subshell then read all NUL-terminated output from the subshell into the current shell (assuming the function doesn't output any NUL chars):

With readarray:
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo'; printf '\0%s\0' "$foo")
capture="${arr[0]%$'\n'}"
foo="${arr[1]}"

The capture="${arr[0]%$'\n'}" is to ensure any newline that update_name_ref_and_echo prints at the end of it's stdout gets removed when populating capture. You could alternatively do IFS= read -r capture <<< "${arr[0]}" if you prefer but that'd probably create a temp file and so be slower.

With a block of reads:
{
    IFS= read -r -d '' capture
    capture="${capture%%$'\n'}"
    IFS= read -r -d '' foo
} < <(update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo'; printf '\0%s' "$foo")

which you can use a function like this for if you prefer not to write IFS= read -r -d '' ... multiple times:
readem() {
    local arg
    for arg; do
        local -n var="$arg"
        IFS= read -r -d '' var
        var="${var%%$'\n'}"
    done
}

readem capture foo < <(update_name_ref_and_echo 'foo'; printf '\0%s\n' "$foo")

It usually isn't an issue but FYI the read/readarrays above would only strip 1 trailing newline from each variables contents while var=$(cmd) would strip all of them. If you might have multiple newlines at the end and want to strip all of them, if present, you could change that readem() function to this or similar (depending on your requirements for handling that):
readem() {
    local arg
    local re=$'(.*[^\n])?\n*$'
    for arg; do
        local -n var="$arg"
        IFS= read -r -d '' var
        [[ "$var" =~ $re ]] &&
            var="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    done
}




Thank you very much, Ed. Your answer addressed all my two questions- explaining the cause of the problem, and providing the fix. It's very kind of you to provide all the different approaches. I really appreciate it!


Why command substitution change the behaviour of name referenced parameter of a function?

Because command substitution runs the command in a subshell which is a separate process. Any changes you make to the environment only affects the subshell's environment. When the command exits, the subshell exits, and any modifications to the subshell's environment go away with it.

Thank you very much for the quick assistant, Glenn. I appreciate it! You answer explains the cause of the problem. It totally makes sense now. Just wondering if you happened to have any suggestions on the fix, so I can capture the output from echo, while allow modifying name referenced parameter or the global variable, at the same time? Thanks again!

As a workaround, you can use a second name-ref:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
update_name_ref_and_echo() {
    local -n name_ref=$1
    name_ref="new value"
    local string_value=bar
    if test $# = 1; then
        echo "$string_value"
    else
        local -n name_ref=$2
        printf -v name_ref %s "$string_value"
    fi
}     
      
foo="old value"
echo "foo before: $foo"
update_name_ref_and_echo foo 
echo "foo after: $foo"

echo "---------------"

foo="old value"
echo "foo before: $foo"
update_name_ref_and_echo foo capture # <==== Notice capture here.
echo "foo after: $foo"
echo "capture after: $capture"

output :
foo before: old value
bar
foo after: new value
---------------
foo before: old value
foo after: new value
capture after: bar


grumbles about function funcname() { blending the legacy 1980s ksh syntax function funcname { and the modern POSIX syntax funcname() { into an amalgam incompatible with both legacy ksh and POSIX
